# ASP Classic consolidating with classes - not sure how to structure presentation

Tags: class, asp-classic

I've got an ASP Classic site I'm maintaining and I want to consolidate the access to objects and properties. I've written some simple classes with properties to get data, insert data, and update data for a particular object. Most of these classes correspond to a single table.

I'm wondering where I should do things like create HTML output for screens, or where I should put methods in that use multiple classes. For example, I might have a student grade class that uses assignments and student information to produce output.

Do I make a "presentation" class that takes recordsets (or arrays?) from the objects and renders the output?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to suggest using WSC's for that. Unlike classes, WSC's can be loaded/implemented conditionally. At the company I work for we built a very stable and fast multi-tier ORM using WSC's. A WSC is an object written in script code and has properties and methods.

[WSC explanation](http://aspalliance.com/414_Windows_Scripting_Components_WSC_in_ASP)
[WSC example](http://precompiled.wordpress.com/tag/asp-wsc-sha1-hmac-encryption/)

Like you, we have a WSC per table, with properties for columns. Furthermore, each WSC has an initialise() method that accepts an ID, and loads all of the object properties with the values from the database for that ID. It also has a save() method. this checks if there is an id present. If not, it executes an INSERT, if there is an id, this is an existing record and it executes an UPDATE. It also has a delete function(). We have a small ASP webpage that can generate these WSC's on the fly for a given table.

Within the WSC we have a data-access-layer object that executes all of the queries in the WSC. Every WSC just builds SQL strings and sends them to the DAL, the DAL returns a recordset (or just executes without results).
This DAL is the only component that needs to know the connectionstring to the database. It can also be used to log all queries if need be.

We also have WSC's for logging/debugging, for translation and one very important one that escapes all SQL to prevent SQL injection.

Back to your question;

Usually you would strife to separate logic from presentation as much as possible. In modern frameworks such as asp.net mvc or django, you can only pass information to a page in a generic dictionary that you can add to, or in a model that you pass onto the page. (A model being one of your class-mapped tables).
If you can mimic this behavior that would give you a good separation of logic and code.

I will tell you what we did to solve the problem you describe, but I'll also tell you our solution is not ideal, and what I would do if we were to start from scratch:

What we do in our current application is to add methods to our WSC's. So suppose we have a user() wsc, that maps to a user table, we can already do stuff like:

```
user.firstname = "erik"
user.lastname = "test"
user.save()
```

We than add "user-stuff" to this WSC, like perhaps a login() function, that accepts a username and password, and returns a user id (or nothing when the login was not successful):

```
dim userid
    userid = user.login("test", "test")
```

This way we separate the logic that belongs to a specific entity by putting it in the WSC it belongs to.

So what we actually do is add logic to the object itself. This is not the way it is done in true OO style. In true Object Oriented programming you would pass objects (like a user-object) around as a parameter or a function-result, and keep your (processing) logic separate. Classic ASP is not truely object-oriented, so we chose to add the logic to the object itself, but in hindsight, something along those lines could propably be achieved in classic asp if you wish.

Also, there are some procedures that raise the question of where they belong. Sending a user a formatted PDF lettter, does the logic go in the user-object or the letter-object?
The way we answered this is just by looking at the code. Do we already have a user WSC available and initialised? Then we could easily add a method to the user. If we need to bulk-send letters, and we are starting with an open letters.wsc, we add functionality to the letters wsc. Honestly, it mostly arranges itself.

If you were to separate your business logic and your ORM (mapping tables to classes or WSCs) completely, then you won't have this problem. That's why modern OO languages are a good solution to this problem. In classic ASP you could do this by putting your processing logic in your ASP pages, and the objects are just there to be used by the processing logic.

What we currently do is we have a dedicated WSC that can store information in a database. We process on one ASP page, but we don't display it. Instead we put our results in this WSC (which stores it in a big key-value table). We then redirect to a different ASP page, which displays the data from that same WSC/table, thus separating code form logic.

[memcached for classic ASP](http://drcarter.info/2011/06/memcached-component-for-classic-asp/)

Since a short while, it's possible to use memcached from classic ASP. memcached is a key-value storage completely in memory, also used by facebook. It is much faster than a database for storage. Would I start over, I would implement it like this:

1. use WSC's to create an ORM like we have now
2. don't put the business logic in the WCS's anymore, put it in ASP pages by default
3. have the asp pages store the results in memcached (this can be simple variables, but also serialised recordsets or even json objects if you're working in jscript instead of vbscript)
4. redirect to a presentation page that can display the information stored in memcached.

Dammit Caveatrob, as you can see I'm pretty passionate about this stuff, it seems like I wrote a small book on implementing this. It would be a lot of work doing this and starting from scratch, and I realise I have said way more than what you asked, but I didn't want to delete this after I wrote it.
I hope some of the information can work in your advantage, even though you propably won't implement this entire framework. ( If you do, let me know :) )

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, we write "pages" as the following:

### BEGIN CONTROLLER

PAGE CONTROLLER CODE (SQL QUERY, PARAMETERS, SESSION, ETC.)

Here we calculate the whole thing for presentation and act to users actions

### END

### BEGIN PRESENTATION

Display html page using server side includes for common html fragments (pagination, common scripts, etc.), and data prepared on controller side.

### END PRESENTATION

In the presentation side (whereever/however you do it) you would call your objects methods to display/retrieve data as needed

I think that, unless its really common, presentation of your business objects shouldn't be capsule into their classes but elsewhere.

Maybe you could build several classes implementing different renderers for your objects.  But I think that most of the time is hard to encapsulate whole presentation into objects :(

Hope this helps!  Cheers!